# Odata and Select Issues

Tags: c#, linq, odata

Have a OData Web Service that I want to query and apply conditional processing to but the following error is being recieved "**Error translating Linq expression to URI: Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation**"

```
var reason = (from x in odataContainer.Table where x.userId == "test" select x.eventReason );
if (eventReason == "Failure")
      // Do something
```

The query does work if I don't make the selection specific i.e select x instead of x.eventReason however I want to avoid pulling back a lot of data by applying a filter.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Which OData .NET client are you using http://www.odata.org/libraries/? Is the issue is for all object types or just for this Table type? You need to add more code and details if you need help.

Comment: Just using Microsoft.Data.OData library and it's happening across all table types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var reason = odataContainer.Table.Where(x => x.UserId == "test").FirstOrDefault().eventReason;
```

This should work!